# How to sort an array of complex objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have this method for sorting an array of objects, but when I have a complex structure, for example:

`const data = [ { title: 'Book title', author: 'John', info: { language: english, pages: 500, price: '$50' }} ]`

I can't sort the second level of the object 'info: {language: english, pages: 500, price:' $ 50 '}'

My Code:

```
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';

interface SortConfigProps {
  key: string;
  direction: string;
}

export const useSortableData = <T>(items: T[]) => {
  const [sortConfig, setSortConfig] = useState<SortConfigProps>(
    {} as SortConfigProps,
  );

  const sortedItems = useMemo(() => {
    const sortableItems = [...items];

    if (sortConfig) {
      sortableItems.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a[sortConfig.key] < b[sortConfig.key]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (a[sortConfig.key] > b[sortConfig.key]) {
          return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
    }
    return sortableItems;
  }, [items, sortConfig]);

  const requestSort = (key: string) => {
    let direction = 'ascending';
    if (
      sortConfig &&
      sortConfig.key === key &&
      sortConfig.direction === 'ascending'
    ) {
      direction = 'descending';
    }
    setSortConfig({ key, direction });
  };

  return { items: sortedItems, requestSort, sortConfig };
};
```

Comment: You could sort a flattened version of the object, if you can guarantee that there will be no overlap in key names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to implement this based on your overall system so for my suggestion, I am going to assume the following:

- You want to keep the data as is for performance or some other reasons (i.e. flattening the object through some kind of "normalizer" is not an option).
- The key cannot be an object, but has to be a string
- Either you or the user can set the key.
- There exists a character or a set of characters that can be used in a key string as a delimiter to construct a tree of keys (e.g. a dot in `'info.price'`, or an arrow in `'info->price'`). An important property of the delimiter is that it is not valid to use it in a flat key (i.e. in the last example something like `data = [{ 'info->price': '$50' }]` is not allowed)

---

Ok now you just need to implement an accessor to use the complex keys on your object, something similar to [Lodash.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get). A simple implementation would be something like:

```js
const DELIMITER = '->';

function get(obj, key) {
  if (!obj) {
    // in case of null or undefined
    return obj;
  }
  if (!key) {
    // empty string or something like that
    return obj;
  }
  if (key.includes(DELIMITER)) {
    const keyComponents = key.split(DELIMITER);
    const firstKeyComponent = keyComponents.shift();
    const newKey = keyComponents.join(DELIMITER);
    return get(obj[firstKeyComponent], newKey)
  }
  return obj[key];
}
```

Emphasis on the simple here, because recalculating `keyComponents` every time is not ideal. You also might want add extra if cases for how to handle strings or arrays, those could cause problems if a key component is a number.

**EDIT:** Also maybe use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to check if a key is identical to a built in Object function, or better yet check if obj is a function and decide how to handle that scenario.

After you have this you can just replace that compare segment of your code with this:

```js
  sortableItems.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
    const aValue = get(a, sortConfig.key);
    const bValue = get(b, sortConfig.key);
    if (aValue < bValue) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (aValue] > bValue) {
      return sortConfig.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
```

And you're good to go for most cases. I don't know how "wild" your data can get so make sure to test a bunch of scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is deep cloning of an object. the spread operator only goes 1 level deep and you are trying to go two. You can use libraries from lodash or other deep cloning. I use the JSON trick.

```
     const [data, setData] = useState(initData);
     function newArray() {
        return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
```

Example shows sorting with two levels: https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-sea-jt220?file=/src/App.js