# JavaScript sort an array of objects based array of properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have for example this dataset:

```
const order = [
  { key: "job", direction: "ascending" },
  { key: "age", direction: "descending" },
];

const records = [
  { name: "christian", age: 40, job: "developer" },
  { name: "andrew", age: 48, job: "developer" },
  { name: "elisabeth", age: 31, job: "floor manager" },
  { name: "oscar", age: 61, job: "floor manager" },
  { name: "gisela", age: 51, job: "area manager" },
  { name: "buffy", age: 27, job: "trainee" },
  { name: "carl", age: 23, job: "trainee" },
];
```

I need to sort the `records` array according to the criteria from `order` array.
I ended up with this solution:

```
const sorted = records.sort(
  (recordA, recordB) =>
    recordA.job.localeCompare(recordB.job) || recordA.age - recordB.age
);
```

But I cant understand how can I use the `order` array instead of hardcoded the `job` and `age` properties. The `order` array can have many properties.

Comment: so you need two array one is sorted on the basis of job(ascending) and another one which is sorted on the basis of age(descending)

Comment: It’d be a lot easier if the `order` array also contained an entry that tells you if the property is to be sorted numerically or lexicographically, at least if you want to keep using `localCompare` and `-`. Alternatively, everything can be generalized with `(a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : 0)`.

Comment: I would look at [this question and its answers for inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65722491/215552).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take a closure over the wanted order and check the value if finite then return the delta or treat the values as string.

Inside sorting function iterate as long as the return value is falsy and take this value as return value for sorting.

```js
const
    sortBy = order => (a, b) => {
        let r;
        order.some(({ key, direction }) => r = (isFinite(a[key]) && isFinite(b[key])
            ? a[key] - b[key]
            : a[key].toString().localeCompare(b[key])        
        ) * (direction === 'ascending' || -1))
        return r;
    },
    records = [{ name: "christian", age: 40, job: "developer" }, { name: "andrew", age: 48, job: "developer" }, { name: "elisabeth", age: 31, job: "floor manager" }, { name: "oscar", age: 61, job: "floor manager" }, { name: "gisela", age: 51, job: "area manager" }, { name: "buffy", age: 27, job: "trainee" }, { name: "carl", age: 23, job: "trainee" }],
    order = [{ key: "job", direction: "ascending" }, { key: "age", direction: "descending" }];

console.log(records.sort(sortBy(order)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just loop over the order data and make the comparisons:

```js
let order = [{ key: "job", direction: "ascending" }, { key: "age", direction: "descending" }];
let records = [{ name: "christian", age: 40, job: "developer" }, { name: "andrew", age: 48, job: "developer" }, { name: "elisabeth", age: 31, job: "floor manager" }, { name: "oscar", age: 61, job: "floor manager" }, { name: "gisela", age: 51, job: "area manager" }, { name: "buffy", age: 27, job: "trainee" }, { name: "carl", age: 23, job: "trainee" }];

records.sort(function (a, b) {
    for (let {key, direction} of order) {
        if (a[key] !== b[key]) return (direction[0] === "a") === (a[key] < b[key]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return 0;
});

console.log(records);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `direction[0] === "a"` you're going to win the code golf :)

Comment: Then I would have left out one `=` or even `direction<"b"` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You could use `(a[key] > b[key]) - (a[key] < b[key])` to compare two values either lexically or numerically (if both are numbers). This could then be used like:

```js
const order = [
  { key: "job", direction: "ascending" },
  { key: "age", direction: "descending" },
];

const records = [
  { name: "christian", age: 40, job: "developer" },
  { name: "andrew", age: 48, job: "developer" },
  { name: "elisabeth", age: 31, job: "floor manager" },
  { name: "oscar", age: 61, job: "floor manager" },
  { name: "gisela", age: 51, job: "area manager" },
  { name: "buffy", age: 27, job: "trainee" },
  { name: "carl", age: 23, job: "trainee" },
];

const compare = (key) => (a, b) => (a[key] > b[key]) - (a[key] < b[key]);
const or = (a, b) => (...v) => a(...v) || b(...v);
 
const sorter = order.map(it => compare(it.key)).reduce(or);
const sorted = records.sort(sorter);
console.log(sorted);
```

<sub>The implementation of `direction` was left to the reader</sub>